# Android Things GPIO interrupt not triggered until after wait() timeout

Tags: java, callback, gpio, android-things

I've got this basic setup, with `interrupt` having been registered from outside as edge-triggered callback for a GPIO pin:

```
public class Foo {

  private static final Object notifier = new Object();

  public static GpioCallback interrupt = pin -> {
    synchronized (notifier) {
      notifier.notifyAll();
    }
    return true;
  };

  public void waitForInterrupt() {

    try {
      synchronized (notifier) {
        notifier.wait(5000);
      }
      Log.d("FOO", "Done.");
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

The timeout of `wait()` is always exhausted, even if the interrupt occurs. Only then is the callback being executed.

Is there a way to execute the callback as soon as it occurs, and if so, how?

Comment: Glad to hear you solved your problem!  However, on Stackoveflow we do not edit solutions into questions.  Please revert your edit and post your solution as an answer, then return in a few days after the self-answer timer has expired and accept that answer.  This is the only way (short of closure) for the system to consider your question resolved.

Comment: Can I ask why you're using wait/notify?  It's not something you generally have to use in Android programming.

Comment: Please add your edit as answer with source code changes.

Comment: Done. Thanks for the heads-up.
@JamesPuderer I am integrating an SPI protocol, where an interrupt pin is being used to signal "ready for new messages" (among other things), so I need to ensure the interrupt has occurred before sending the next one. Is there a better way than wait()?

Comment: This could be done in a simpler way and without the need for synchonisation. However you haven't shared enough of a code example for me to help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by moving the call to `waitForInterrupt` to its own thread. Before, it was called by a different callback function, now that one just starts the thread. I'm guessing that waiting for callbacks inside a callback is asking for trouble, maybe GPIO callbacks can only be executed in series..?

Answer (score 1):

You probably don't want to be using notify/wait at all, especially on the main thread.

Android uses an event loop to do things like post results to callbacks.  If you wait on the main thread, you will be blocking the event loop, ensuring that your callback never gets called (and your application will be unresponsive in general).